# How to inherit django model to make models records independent?

Tags: python, django

I'm creating ToDo app and I want to archive task when completed.
To do so I have created Todo model and TodoArchive, which inherits after Todo:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Todo(models.Model):
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    story = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="-")
    project = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task


class TodoArchive(Todo):
    date_archived = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'ARCH {self.task} - {self.date_added}'
```

After that I loop through each task in view and create new archive object:

```
def archive_completed(request):
    for todo in Todo.objects.all():
        if todo.complete:
            archive_todo = TodoArchive(task=todo.task, story=todo.story,
                                       project=todo.project, complete=todo.complete,
                                       date_added=todo.date_added)

            archive_todo.save()
            todo.delete()

    return redirect('home')
```

But after that elements moved to Archive model belongs to both models as shown on the picture below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVxHy.png

The effect is that when I delete element from one model it removes it from the other immediately.

Does anyone knows why and how to eliminate this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You have modeled [Multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)

So when you create a TodoArchive  you are actually creating both Todo and TodoArchive  models ( fields from Todo are in todo table and rest is in second one)

If you want to have dry approach in model definition you can use [Abstract base class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

```
class TodoBasic(models.Model):
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    story = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="-")
    project = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Todo(TodoBasic):

     def __str__(self):
        return self.task


class TodoArchive(TodoBasic):
    date_archived = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'ARCH {self.task} - {self.date_added}'
```

---

Even better in my opinion would be to have single table and just additional field by which you filter if it is archived or not ( is_archived )

```
class Todo(models.Model):
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    story = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="-")
    project = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_archived = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

So you could filter by

```
   archived_tasks = Task.objects.filter(is_archived=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the Django documentation on [Model instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.delete), the `delete()` method has two optional arguments, one of which I believe is the key to your problem: `keep_parents` that is set to `False` by default.

You may need to change your model scheme. In your *models.py* `TodoArchive` inherits from `Todo`. You can keep the parent not the child and it's the only logical way if you think about it. So in your case, The `Todo` model should inherit from `TodoArchive` and the delete method should be performed as: `todo.delete(keep_parents=True)`.